# Disable Button by code

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I need to know how to enable/disable button through code;

My workings so far;

```
             var button= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#id> #button1')[0];
button.disable();
```

i also tried ;

```
button.setDisable(true);
```

Nothing worked. what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Have you tried: button.disabled = 'true'; or button.disabled = true;

Comment: Either of those method calls would disable the button, so perhaps you're not getting the button correctly.  Do you really have a container with an id value of `'id'` that the button with an id of `'button1'` is a direct child of?

Comment: I just made the code short by adding 1 container but, there are 2 more containers where i didn't put it there.

Comment: OK, but the point is: are you sure you're getting the button you think you're getting by that call, because the way you're disabling it is fine.

Comment: Yes, i am getting the correct button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just hide the button?
      button.Visible = false;

Comment: just tried `.setVisible(false);` instead and it hid the button. what i want is to disable it. But your post was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
button.set({disabled: 'disabled'});
```